# Firebase rules that supports only requests from my apps

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have two apps registered in Firebase, say App A and App B. I haven't setup any firebase authentication system but I want to allow requests only from App A and App B. I want to check if the request is coming from my apps and then only perform the actions. If the request is from somewhere else then just reject it.

I want to have this security for Cloud Firestore and Firebase Storage.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, this feature isn't available, some of this will be rolling out in the near future using the new App Check: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check

At this time, App check only supports:

- Realtime Database
- Cloud Storage
- Cloud Functions (callable functions)