# What rules do I set in my firebase real-time database such that only specific users registered in my project can access it?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new to Firebase. Recently I registered my `web-app` and my `android app` in my firebase project. I have a Realtime Database in my project where the following rules are set:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth !== null",
    ".write": "auth !== null"
  }
}
```

I just got an email today from firebase saying that my database is insecure as any authenticated user can modify it. So my question is what rules do I set in my database such that only some users registered in my firebase project (i.e., my `web app` and my `android app`) can access it?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to allow only users of your app to access the data, is to [implement Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) in the application and then [enforce](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/enable-enforcement) that for the Realtime Database.

This topic has been covered quite a few times before, so I recommend also checking out:

- [Locking down Firebase DB access to specific apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52018041/locking-down-firebase-db-access-to-specific-apps)
- [Firebase rules that supports only requests from my apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68172086/firebase-rules-that-supports-only-requests-from-my-apps)